# How many times does AWS Lambda fuctions retry to be invoked asynchronously?

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-lambda, serverless, aws-serverless

I'm learning AWS Lambda, a bit confused about this one, in official [FaQ](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/faqs/) it says:

Q: What happens if my Lambda function fails during processing an event?

On failure, Lambda functions being invoked synchronously will respond with an exception. **Lambda functions being invoked asynchronously are retried at least 3 times.** Events from Amazon Kinesis streams and Amazon DynamoDB streams are retried until the Lambda function succeeds or the data expires. Kinesis and DynamoDB Streams retain data for a minimum of 24 hours.

However, in the Lambda console, it can only be selected as 0, 1, 2 (shown in the figure below)
[image]
[image]

Comment: There is no need in retry to invoke Lambda asynchronously. Is it what you're asking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `3 times` you mention contains the first try.

If you test, you can find lambda retry twice by default on asynchronous-invocation(for me, s3 event notification).

In addition, other the two references are saying like the below

[reference1](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/11/aws-lambda-supports-max-retry-attempts-event-age-asynchronous-invocations/?nc1=h_ls)

> Lambda attempts to run it two more times by default.

[reference2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/retries-on-errors.html)

> Asynchronous invocation – Lambda retries function errors twice.

Comment: This makes sense, the first try + two more retries, thank you.